# Showing Webbrowser History appear in as a tabpages

Tags: vb.net

Anyone who knows how to show full page history , rather than creating another form with list view and naming it history. I would like to show my history appear like Google Chrome or safari. To be precise safari. Am working on a tabbed WebBrowser vb

Comment: Browsers make lists of sites visited as they are used. This is why if you have 2 or more browsers you cannot see what sites were visited in the other browsers only the sites visited using that browser. If you are building your own browser you are going to have to collate a list of sites visited and then show them on your own history page.

Comment: I think you didn't get it,what I want is a history page that appears like the one of chrome....chrome://history...just like that I have a tabbed WebBrowser using Microsoft WebBrowser